# Backup в sql 2000

Tags: sql

Можно ли вывести результат комманды backup database в grid, а не messages.

Comment: Требуется для скрипта на autoit? он может читать grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось, с помощи можуля с osql

Answer (score 0):

Можно программно подписаться на событие SqlCommand.InfoMessage и реализовать вывод этого в грид.

Comment: А по подробней можно, если не трудно. Допустим, надо чтобы пришел какой-нибудь ответ от sql при выполнения backup, типа completed, что бы считать его из Grid.